# Android UI LinearLayout out of "phone screen"

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

I am new to android. I am using Android Studio 2.3.1. I am trying to create a UI and as you can see from the attached picture, the LinearLayout is coming "out" of the phone screen. I tried to play around with several properties like layout_gravity, gravity, etc., but none seemed to get the LinearLayout inside the phone screen.

Here is the screenshot of my current layout behavior:

[image]

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="264dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="51dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/leaf"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/leaf" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="OFIS Companion" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/settingscog" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middleSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:editable="false"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="371dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:duplicateParentState="false"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false"
            android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:keepScreenOn="false"
            android:layerType="none"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its because the orientation is horizontal.. change it to vertical..

Comment: The `middleSection` `LinearLayout` is horizontal, as, I believe, @ZeroOne is referring to. The `TextView` in it has `match_parent` as the `layout_width`, so it's pushing the other `LinearLayout` out the side.

Comment: Thanks Mike and ZeroOne. That makes it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `middleSection` LinearLayout orientation is `horizontal` and you have used `TextView` width `match_parent`. `TextView` consumes the full `width` of `middleSection` LinearLayout that's why `child` LineraLayout showing outside of screen.

change `middleSection` LinearLayout `orientation` to `vertical`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="264dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="51dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/leaf"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/leaf" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="OFIS Companion" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/settingscog" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middleSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:editable="false"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="371dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:duplicateParentState="false"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false"
            android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:keepScreenOn="false"
            android:layerType="none"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#ff0000">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**FYI,** Just for test I have used `android:background="#ff0000"` to mark this `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The image view is going out of screen as you don't know about weightsum and layout weight so try not to use it in start.

Though for your problem i am giving you a solution

weightsum is something which you use to define as the maximum width available in horizontally oriented linear layout and 
similarly 
maximum height available for vertical linear layout and now in child layouts you have to divide the weightsum as you want.

If you are using horizontal layout as the case is here... use 0dp or dip as width params in children and 
make sure that you are distributing the childs such layout_weights that the sum comes less than weightsum.

Rather than that... You have to take care of your android basics first of all.

Start reading documentation.